# Yii2, исключить значения из запроса к БД

Tags: php, база-данных, yii2, activerecord

Как в Yii2 исключить значения из запроса к БД
Например:

```
$User->find()->where(['<>', 'name', 'admin'])->all();
```

Исключит 'admin' из столбца 'name'

Но если всё то же самое написать в виде массива:

```
$User->find()->where(['<>', 'name', ['admin', 'someUser']])->all();
```

Уже будет вызвано исключение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ в Оф. документации: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail

Вместо оператора `'<>'` можно использовать оператор `'not in'`, тогда третьим аргументом можно передать массив:

```
$User->find()->where(['not in', 'name', ['admin', 'someUser']])->all();
```